# Photon, How to access Photon Recorder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, voice, photon

I'm trying to access Photon's recorder component, but I don't know how to reference it properly,
I think it would be because of the namespaces I'm not using.

I've got:

```
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
```

I was thinking I would need something like:

```
using Photon.Voice;
```

Or something like it, but it doesn't get me the component.
I've tried doing `PhotonVoiceRecorder`, `Recorder`, `PhotonVoice` but none of these work.
I've also done some google searches but haven't found anything that has helped me.

I'm trying to get this because I want a push-to-talk function so it isn't always listening to what the player says.

I hope you can help me!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more scrounging around in Photons manual I had to put:

```
using Photon.Voice.Unity;
```

at the top of my project, and then just:

```
Recorder recorder;
```

as my component.

Cheers!